# How to obtain a template parameter pack of integers int a function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, default-arguments

Say I want to have a function like:

```
void reset()
{
    (std::get</*pack of integers from 0 to 4*/>(someTuple).reset(), ...);
}
```

I did it with a helper function like this:

```
template < size_t... Indexes >
void reset(std::integer_sequence<size_t, Indexes...>)
{
    (std::get<Indexes>(someTuple).reset(), ...);
}
void reset()
{
    reset(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t,5>{});
}
```

But can I achieve this with just one function? The attempt like:

```
template < size_t... Indexes >
void reset(std::integer_sequence<size_t, Indexes...> = std::make_integer_sequence<size_t,5>{})
{
    (std::get<Indexes>(someTuple).reset(), ...);
}
```

failed as the call `reset()` resolved to `reset<>(std::integer_sequence<size_t>)` rather than to `reset<0,1,2,3,4>(std::integer_sequence<size_t,0,1,2,3,4>)`. I am using the latest snapshot of GCC-7.0.0

Comment: what you have is the way to go, imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve something like this with a defaulted template parameter:

```
template <class S = std::make_index_sequence<5>>
struct reset; // intentionally undefined

template <size_t... Is>
struct reset<std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    template <class Tuple>
    static void impl(Tuple& t) {
        (std::get<Is>(t).reset(), ...);
    }
};

reset<>::impl(someTuple);
```

but not in a function (since such a thing would require partial specialization of function templates, which is not supported by the language).

Instead, just create a helper lambda for inline parameter pack unpacking:

```
void reset() {
    indexer<5>()([&](auto I){
        std::get<I>(someTuple).reset();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of generic lambda and some helper struct like this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct iterate;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct iterate<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
   template <class Lambda>
   void operator()(Lambda lambda) {
      lambda(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}...);
   }
};

struct Foo {
   void reset() {}
};

void reset() {
   std::tuple<Foo, Foo, Foo> bar;
   iterate<std::tuple_size<decltype(bar)>::value>{}([&](auto... is) {
      (std::get<is>(bar).reset(), ...);
   });
}

int main() {
   reset();
}
```